SAP material master views during creation
When I create a material in SAP ERP (via e.g. MM01) I can select which views I want created.
Let's say I select only BasicData1, fill in necessary details and save.
Now in table MARA I'll see a maintenance status = K (BasicData) in field VPSTA/PSTAT.
However, maintenance status K actually encompasses following views:

BasicData1
BasicData2
Extended SPP BasicData
WM Execution
WM Packaging

However, this I don't see in table MARA - actually I have yet to find where I can check/verify this - and my question is thus - how do I see which actual views are created for the material - not just the maintenance status!
I've tried looking at various transaction code like MM01 but also MM50 to trigger which views gets created when.
Further I've been trying to look into SPRO for the configuration, however my limited knowledge (I'm not a consultant) doesn't give me any results.
